# How to add custom attribute in magento 2 customer export dynamically while click on export button

Tags: magento2, customer, export, customer-csv

When I click on the export button, I want to add a custom attribute in the customer data export file.

I am trying to override the `vendor/magento/module-ui/model/export/ConvertToCsv.php` file But when I click on the export button the navigation doesn't come to the ConvertToCsv.php file.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: which data i.e. customer custom attribute ?

Comment: I want to pass the custom encrypted value while exporting csv generating

Comment: This is more of a freelance gig rather than a question.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/013c82c42a84f79a0b870f641b9d21c4e7b0a2ba/app/code/Magento/CustomerImportExport/Model/Export/Customer.php#L119

this is export function on customer and

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/013c82c42a84f79a0b870f641b9d21c4e7b0a2ba/app/code/Magento/CustomerImportExport/Model/Export/Customer.php#L156
This is export Item

I would suggest playing around this for adding something more to export.

Comment: Hi Rex, where we add the custom attribute or values added in csv file

Answer (score 0):

**How to Include Custom Column in Export To CSV in Magento 2?**

> Create app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" />
</config>
```

> Create app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Module\Vendor\Model\Export;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider;
use Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv as ConvertToCsvParent;
/**
 * Class ConvertToCsv
 */
class ConvertToCsv extends ConvertToCsvParent
{
    /**
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directory;
    /**
     * @var MetadataProvider
     */
    protected $metadataProvider;
    /**
     * @var int|null
     */
    protected $pageSize = null;
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;
    /**
     * @var Product
     */
    private $productHelper;
    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    private $timezone;
    /**
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param MetadataProvider $metadataProvider
     * @param int $pageSize
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        Filter $filter,
        MetadataProvider $metadataProvider,
        Product $productHelper,
        TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        $pageSize = 200
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        $this->metadataProvider = $metadataProvider;
        $this->pageSize = $pageSize;
        $this->productHelper = $productHelper;
        parent::__construct($filesystem, $filter, $metadataProvider, $pageSize);
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
    }
    /**
     * Returns CSV file
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function getCsvFile()
    {
        $component = $this->filter->getComponent();
        $name = md5(microtime());
        $file = 'export/' . $component->getName() . $name . '.csv';
        $this->filter->prepareComponent($component);
        $this->filter->applySelectionOnTargetProvider();
        $dataProvider = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider();
        $fields = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);
        $options = $this->metadataProvider->getOptions();
        $this->directory->create('export');
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($file, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getHeaders($component));
        $i = 1;
        $searchCriteria = $dataProvider->getSearchCriteria()
            ->setCurrentPage($i)
            ->setPageSize($this->pageSize);
        $totalCount = (int)$dataProvider->getSearchResult()->getTotalCount();
        while ($totalCount > 0)
        {
            $items = $dataProvider->getSearchResult()->getItems();
            if ($component->getName() == 'customer_listing')
            {
                foreach ($items as $item)
                {
                    $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($item, $component->getName());
                    $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($item, $fields, $options));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($item, $component->getName());
                    $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($item, $fields, $options));
                }
            }
            $searchCriteria->setCurrentPage(++$i);
            $totalCount = $totalCount - $this->pageSize;
        }
        $stream->unlock();
        $stream->close();
        return [
            'type' => 'filename',
            'value' => $file,
            'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
        ];
    }
}
```

Modify this file as per your requirement

Execute the below command:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

That’s it.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout BSS Commerce as they have an extension for that. https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-custom-product-attribute-export-extension.html

Comment: I want to add the data on the export csv file while it generating csv